# How do I verify credentials through a text file instead of through the authorization file?

Tags: php, authentication, session, flat-file

I have a PHP login script with a basic form, it leads to this file which is the authorization file that contains the credentials, but I want this file to check a text file for a matching username and password from a text file formatted like `username:password` or something similar. Anyone got any ideas?

```
<?php

if ( ! isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) )
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

$credentials = [
   'username' => 'TESTUSER',
   'password' => 'TESTPASS'
];

if ( $credentials['username'] !== $_POST['username'] 
      OR $credentials['password'] !== $_POST['password'] )
{    
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit();
}
session_start();
$_SESSION["000000"] = "1"; 
header('Location:' . 'index.php');
exit();
```

Comment: You should look into better ways of providing login functionality, hardcoding them and storing in a text file located on the server is very insecure, let alone the fact you seem to be storing them as plain text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice of the type of persistent storage is up to you, but you should:

**Never** store passwords as plain text, use [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) before storing them.

Then, on login, use [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify that the password matches the hash in your storage medium (e.g. database / flat file).

Example:

```
<?php
echo password_hash("somepassword", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$hash = '$2y$10$f.iC/tadtwSws25fW2zRg./.xlY.mRK82Ys9M4acbPU/b614vA1vy';

if (password_verify('somepassword', $hash)) {
    echo 'The password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'The password is not valid';
}
```

You can play around with this [demo](https://3v4l.org/uLIID)

**UPDATE:** A bare bones example of a flat file (`.json`) user store / login-verify script. You still need to do data validation and sanitization on the user input, and decide if a flat file store is the best solution / sufficient for the level of security your application requires.

There are two files:

1. `index.php` the app - user store / login-verification
2. `users.json` the flat file database (user credentials: `name` and `password`)

`index.php` renders two forms, the first can be used to add users to `users.json`, and the second to do login verification.

`index.php`

```
<?php
function getForm(string $submitName, string $submitValue)
{
    $form = <<<HEREDOC
    <form method="POST">
    <label for="username">User Name : </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required>
    <label for="password">Password : </label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" required>
    <input type="submit" name="$submitName" value="$submitValue">
    </form>
HEREDOC;
    return $form;
}
// build forms
$userForm = getForm('submit_user', 'Add User');
$loginForm = getForm('submit_login', 'Login');

/* add a new user to flat file database */
echo $userForm;
if (isset($_POST['submit_user'])) {
    // retrieve user input - you still need to do data validation and sanitizing
    $userName = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
    $passWord = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : null;
    $passWord = password_hash($passWord, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // store a hash
    // get user.json file
    $file = "./users.json";
    $users = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
    // insert new user credentials
    $users['users'][] = ['name' => $userName, 'password' => $passWord];
    // write  to flat file database
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users));
}
/* login - verify user credentials */
echo $loginForm;
if (isset($_POST['submit_login'])) {
    // retrieve user input - you still need to do data validation and sanitizing
    $userName = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
    $passWord = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

    // get user.json file
    $file = "./users.json";
    $users = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

    // verify user
    foreach ($users['users'] as $key => $value) {
        if (strtolower($value['name']) === strtolower($userName)) {
            $hash = $value['password'];
            $verify = password_verify($passWord, $hash); // verify
            if ($verify === true) {
                echo 'User Login Validated';
            } else echo 'Login Not Valid';
        }
    }
}
```

The flat file users database: `users.json`

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "Jack",
      "password": "$2y$10$FBLkEDGX3I6HAVgptJ6q1ujo5K6cFtZn2wNKXKUhoWGNtcwfsRlpi"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jill",
      "password": "$2y$10$yKp79.HujKW3yFvxPDYvqePcUJ9uLWJ92d5TpSy62YtuRTezWrsna"
    },
    {
      "name": "Annie",
      "password": "$2y$10$eWctVmNAadkf138J0iTVr.5u7vmRl9vcglAhSEjbp0WqQphKFjwYC"
    }
  ]
}
```